# SharePoint throttling and web services

Tags: 2010, list, web-services

I am trying to know how throttling in SharePoint affects web services.

For example if a list contains 20 000 items and throttling is set to 2000, if I use the `Lists.GetListItems()` method to get the items what will the result be? Will it contains 2000 or an error message?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will give you an error message. Additionally, it also depends through which user account this code has been called as Administrators have different thresholds for listview than a regular user.

**Edit:**

The exception message will be:

> The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view
>   threshold enforced by the administrator.

Comment: Can you add a link or reference that describes this error? (The form of the XML returned...)

Comment: I edited your question to add the exception message. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running code as Farm Admin throttling settings are ignored and you can retrieve as much data as you need.

If you are a site collection administrator 'List View Threshold for Auditors and Administrators' applies, so by default you are limited to 20.000 list items.

Otherwise 'List View Threshold' will apply.